# yml Rules changes and !reference

Tags: reference, gitlab, yaml, rules

I use reference for my jobs's rules :

```
   .rules_base:
  rules:
    CAS_1: $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"                #CAS_1 WHEN PUSH INTO BRANCH
    CAS_2: $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"                #CAS_2 WHEN PUSH INTO MASTER
    CAS_3: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"                                                                                     #CAS_3 WHEN MERGE BRANCH INTO MASTER
    CAS_4: $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[1-9]+$/ && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == null && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event" #CAS_4 WHEN TAG INTO BRANCH
    CAS_5: $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.0+\.0+$/ && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == null && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"         #CAS_5 WHEN TAG INTO MASTER



    clone_job:
      tags:
        - EXEMPLE
      stage: clone
      needs : []
      rules:
        - if: !reference [.rules_base, rules, CAS_1]
        - if: !reference [.rules_base, rules, CAS_2]
        - if: !reference [.rules_base, rules, CAS_3]
        - if: !reference [.rules_base, rules, CAS_4]
        - if: !reference [.rules_base, rules, CAS_5]
          changes:
            - /*.cpp
            - /*.h
            - /*.xml
      script:
```

changes doesn't work.

Job start when I push a change on .md file in branch or master.

Do you have some ideas ?

Regards

Comment: which version of gitlab do you use ?

Comment: Hello,GitLab Community Edition 14.1.3

Comment: unfortunately, rules keyword support has been introduced in GitLab 14.3 (see [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#reference-tags) )

Comment: now available in gitlab 14.3 https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/09/22/gitlab-14-3-released/#support-merging-cicd-rules-arrays-with-reference